# Why do my GitHub pull requests need to be rebased after each commit to master?

Tags: github, git-rebase, pull-request

I'm having an issue where GitHub doesn't automatically rebase/merge my pull requests at all, even if commits to master since the PR branch was created don't even touch the same files the PR itself touches, so there aren't any merge conflicts at all.

I know this is possible in GitHub, I've encountered a few repositories myself where PRs don't require a rebase and merge conflicts are automatically resolved.

[The repository in question is here.](https://github.com/pydata/sparse)

I've tried going through the project settings but I cannot seem to find a setting that says that this is an issue. Also, if I rebase my PRs manually, it usually happens automatically without me being prompted to resolve any conflics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is configured in the [required status checks section](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-status-checks/), found in **Settings** → **Branches** → **Protected Branches**. The relevant setting is "Require branches to be up to date before merging".

If this feature is enabled, and [status checking is set to "strict" (it is by default)](https://help.github.com/articles/types-of-required-status-checks/), then

> you'll need to bring the head branch up to date after other collaborators merge pull requests to the protected base branch.